# Open each path in a file and search for a pattern in each file

Tags: linux, search

I have a text file as below

```
/some path1/filename1
/some path2/filename2
/some path3/filename3
.
.
.
```

I have to go through this text file, open each file and then search for a pattern string and then print the filenames where the matching string is found

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Not bad; first read in the lines from the file into a variable.
`grep` for pattern in file name stored in that variable.
Either directly pass pattern to grep or store pattern in variable used below:

```
while read f; do 
   grep -l $pattern $f
done < listOfFiles.txt
```

Comment: I had actually formatted better on multiple lines and indented. oh well.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash
while read line
do
  current_file=$line
  grep -l "your pattern" $current_file
done < "path/to/firstfile"
```

Using `grep -l` in a loop should work